# How to continuosly increase or decrease of a value using onLongPressed property in RawMaterialButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app with the following element

[image]

My code for butons is:-

```
RawMaterialButton(
      child: Icon(
        symbol,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
        width: 56.0,
        height: 56.0,
      ),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
      elevation: 6.0,
      onPressed: action,
    )
```

`action` is user defined function. I want it so that if I keep pressing plus or minus button the value will increase or decrease accordingly. How can I do that? I want to avoid using `Timer` class and prefer using loops.

Comment: I know you'd like to avoid using a Timer. But I think that's the best way. Reason being that you've got to specify a minimum duration for the increment. If you use a for loop, the value will increase based on the speed of the phone (correct me if I'm wrong), and that doesn't sound so practical.

Comment: @WilsonOWilson What do you mean value will increase based on speed of phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Timer very easily but as you don't want to use, you must have to use future(async) to achieve so.

I made Following demo for you. I hope it helps.

```
 int counter = 0;
  bool ontap = false;

  subtract() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    setState(() {
      counter--;
    });
    if (ontap) {
      subtract();
    }
  }

  addcounter() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
    if (ontap) {
      addcounter();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.red),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    //  ontap = true;
                    subtract();
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    ontap = true;
                    subtract();
                  },
                  onLongPressEnd: (_) {
                    setState(() {
                      ontap = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    addcounter();
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    ontap = true;
                    addcounter();
                  },
                  onLongPressEnd: (_) {
                    setState(() {
                      ontap = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```